# Disable redirect for specific requests with the same client using HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I would like to know how I can disable redirect for specific requests when using HttpClient. Right now, my client either allows or disables redirects for all its request. I want to be able to make some requests with redirects but some with redirect disable, all with the same client. Is it possible?

Example of using two clients (this is what I want to avoid):

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Redirected client
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        client.execute(get);

        // Non-redirected client
        CloseableHttpClient client2 = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
        HttpGet get2 = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        client2.execute(get2);
    }
}
```

Comment: based on what parameter do you want to take decision to redirect or not?

Comment: Just a boolean that I change in my code. I want to keep enabling/disabling redirects throughout a login process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement your own `RedirectStrategy` to handle redirection as you want and use `setRedirectStrategy` of `HttpClientBuilder` to let http client use your redirection strategy.

You can check [DefaultRedirectStrategy](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/source-code/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java) and [LaxRedirectStrategy](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/source-code/org/apache/http/impl/client/LaxRedirectStrategy.java) implementations for reference.

Important part is `isRedirected` method of `RedirectStrategy`. You need to return `true` or `false` depending if you want to redirect specific request or not. Http request executor [will be calling](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/source-code/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/RedirectExec.java) this method before doing actual redirection.

For example you can extend `DefaultRedirectStrategy` and override `isRedirected` method

```
...
public class MyRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {
...
    @Override
    public boolean isRedirected(
        final HttpRequest request,
        final HttpResponse response,
        final HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
        // check request and return true or false to redirect or not
    ...
    }
}
```